# Error 414 When sending invoice to Amazon MWS with _UPLOAD_VAT_INVOICE_

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

I'm trying to send invoices to amazon mws through _UPLOAD_VAT_INVOICE_ following the java example in this guide:
[Link](https://m.media-amazon.com/images/G/01/B2B/DeveloperGuide/vat_calculation_service__dev_guide_H383rf73k4hsu1TYRH139kk134yzs.pdf)

pdf file is a simple invoice of 85 kb
The error is status code 414 that is "Uri too long"

Debugging original amazon class MarketplaceWebServiceClient I see this:

```
    if( request instanceof SubmitFeedRequest ) {

    // For SubmitFeed, HTTP body is reserved for the Feed Content and the function parameters 
    // are contained within the HTTP header
    SubmitFeedRequest sfr = (SubmitFeedRequest)request;

    method = new HttpPost( config.getServiceURL() + "?" + getSubmitFeedUrlParameters( parameters ) );
```

getSubmitFeedUrlParameters method takes every parameter and add it to querystring. One of these parameters is contentMD5 from:
String contentMD5 = Base64.encodeBase64String(pdfDocument);
So there is a very large string representing pdf file passed as parameter. This causes error 414

But that class is the original one taken from MaWSJavaClientLibrary-1.1.jar

Can anybody help me please?

Thanks

Comment: I add some additional info after debugging

Answer (score 1):

For the last 2 days I was working on the same problem, 
I changed like this and it works now

```java
InputStream contentStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(pdfDocument);
String contentMD5 =computeContentMD5Header(new ByteArrayInputStream(pdfDocument));

public static String computeContentMD5Header(InputStream inputStream) {

        // Consume the stream to compute the MD5 as a side effect.
        DigestInputStream s;
        try {
            s = new DigestInputStream(inputStream,
                    MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5"));

            // drain the buffer, as the digest is computed as a side-effect
            byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
            while (s.read(buffer) > 0)
                ;

            return new String(

            org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64(s
                    .getMessageDigest().digest()), "UTF-8");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```